# "Bad file descriptor" when reading from pipe in the fork process in python3.4

Tags: python, linux, pipe

I use python3.4's os.pipe to do IPC bettwen father process and child process,
passing the pipe args by os.execlp args

```
  self.child_pipe_read=int(sys.argv[2])
  self.child_pipe_write=int(sys.argv[3])
```

...

```
  os.execlp('python3','python3','child_test.py',str(pid),str(self.child_pipe_read) ,str(self.child_pipe_write))
```

however,when I use this:

```
msg=os.read(self.child_pipe_read,32)
```

throw Error OSError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor

and then I try to write to the pipe:

```
 os.write(self.parent_pipe_write,(msg+'\n').encode())
```

BrokenPipeError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe

I saw the python3.4's doc,find this:

"Changed in version 3.4: The new file descriptors are now non-inheritable"
but I don't know What's the meaning of it?
How can I IPC with pipe?

Comment: Your code does not even show the pipe creation. Please add it. Also, see how to [create a minimal, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for tips on maximizing the usefulness of answers you will get.

Answer (score 1):

It is considered a security vulnerability to allow FDs to be inherited by default, hence the change for Python 3.4. You must explicitly mark the FD as inheritable by calling `os.set_inheritable(fd, True)`. Note that this function is new in Python 3.4.

Comment: `self.child_pipe_read,self.parent_pipe_write=os.pipe()`
 `self.parent_pipe_read,self.child_pipe_write=os.pipe()`
 `os.set_inheritable(self.child_pipe_read, True)`
 `os.set_inheritable(self.child_pipe_write, True)`
 `os.set_inheritable(self.parent_pipe_read, True)`
 `os.set_inheritable(self.parent_pipe_write, True)`

Comment: I have even tried as blow,Still Throw  OSError Bad file descriptor in my child process ,however..